# What is the reason for the controller action to produce 404 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i have the following controller with an action `GetPagedList`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;

        public DataController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            this._config = config;
        }

        
        [HttpGet("GetPagedList")]       
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPagedList(int pageNum, int pageSize, string sOrder)
        { 
        //some code here
        }
  }
```

Then i put a break point on the constructor of the `DataController`

[image]

Then i have tried to call the method `GetPagedList` from postman and browser. But in both cases they did not even hit the break point at the constructor and returned **404 error**

**On postman**

[image]

**On Browser**
[image]

I would like to know why this happens and how do i fix this?

Comment: The url generated by standard manner for 'TodoItemsController' is 'api/TodoItems'. Not 'api/TodoItemsController'.

Comment: @XWIKO can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The link in the answer from Adam G points to how the url is created. Part of you URL is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The routing convention set on line 19 will place your controller at `/api/Data`, not `/api/DataController`. ASP NET Core doesn't include the "Controller" suffix in the route.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area

Comment: i totally missed that :)....thanks for spotting it !